# Defining `Comparable` for optional types in Swift 1.2

Tags: swift, generics, compare

```
import SwiftyJSON

public typealias FeedItem = JSON

extension FeedItem {
    var id: Int { get { return self["id"].intValue } }
}

public func <(lhs: FeedItem, rhs: FeedItem) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id < rhs.id
}

public func ==(lhs: FeedItem, rhs: FeedItem) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}

extension FeedItem:Comparable {}

extension Optional : Comparable {}

public func < <T>(l:T?, r:T?) -> Bool {
    if let a=l,b=r {
        return a < b
    } else if (l==nil) && (r != nil) { return true }
    else { return false }
}

public func == <T>(l:T?, r:T?) -> Bool {
    if let a=l, b=r {
        return a==b
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

First, it should read `extension Optional<T where T:Comparable>: Comparable` but swift 1.2 does not allow that. Anyway I can express the constraint more explicitly rather than expecting the reader to realize the fact by noticing `return a < b` and `return a==b` ?

Second (and apparently more important): the code above works when I use `<` and `>` but `minElement` and `maxElement` both return `nil` when a `nil` is present in their input no matter what and `min` and `max` fall into infinite recursion:

```
    let items: [FeedItem?] = [ nil, .Some(JSON(["id":2])), .Some(JSON(["id":1])) ]

    println(items[0]?.id) // nil
    println(items[1]?.id) // Optional(2)
    println(items[2]?.id) // Optional(1)
    println(items[0] < items[1]) // true
    println(items[1] < items[2]) // false
    println(items[2] < items[1]) // true
    println(minElement(items)) // nil
    println(maxElement(items)) // nil
    println( min(items[0],items[2]) ) // nil
    println( min(items[2],items[1]) ) // crashes due to infinite recursion
```

I'm no debug (or swift) expert but from what I can gather in XCode I believe the

```
if let a=l,b=r {
    return a < b
}
```

part somehow misses the point that `a` and `b` are *not* `Optional`s but `FeedItem`s. I expect the `a < b` should call the `<` operator on `FeedItem` and *not* the one on `Optional` but apparently this is exactly what happens; i.e. `a < b` resolves to the same function it is called from (that is, the `<` for `Optional`s) and thus a recursion happens. I might be wrong though.

Insights ?